# How can I format a datetime column to only print hh:mm:ss in an ace report?

Tags: datetime, informix

Informix-SQL 4.10:

I have a `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND` column and would like to just printout the hours, minutes and second (HH:MM:SS) in an ACE report. I tried the following three ACE statements, but they all gave compiler errors:

```
PRINT TimeStampCol USING "HH:MM:SS"
PRINT TimeStampCol HOUR TO SECOND
PRINT TimeStampCol[12,19]
```

Comment: I casted the datetime column to a local ACE char variable and was able to print the desired format by subscripting the variable [12,19], but still interested in finding out how to format datetime column for printing in ACE.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the arguably misnamed EXTEND function, either directly in the ACE formatting code or, if worst comes to worst, as an extra value in the final SELECT statement.

Try:

```
PRINT EXTEND(TimeStampCol, HOUR TO SECOND)
```

Failing that, use the expression in the SELECT statement, remembering to give it a name.

Comment: EXTEND is not a valid in 4.10 ACE or SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

If `EXTEND`is not valid, can't you cast it to `DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND` on the projection clause? Or, as a last resort, cast it to `CHAR(19)` and extract a substring? Just a guest, I don't have a environment that match up your requirements.